# Lost access to Instagram account

Tags: instagram, account-recovery, instagram-account

I have lost access to my Instagram account since it became unlinked with my Facebook account. Every time I try login with Facebook, it takes to creating a new Instagram account option. I tried resetting my password but the email ID I logged in with, I don't have access to it anymore since I don't have it's password. What should I do? I can't recover my email.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have access of associated email or your account is not linked with Facebook. You can not recover your account. See [Instagram help](https://help.instagram.com/409847499070242):

> If you can't access the email you registered with and you didn't link your Instagram account to Facebook, we're not able to give you access to this account.